# Changing Buffer Size of QMediaPlayer

Tags: qt, qt5, multimedia

I have implemented a Videoplayer using Qt5.1 QMediaPlayer, however I would like to know if there is a way to control the buffer sizes for streaming media from a URL so as to cater for different connection speeds. In addition, is there a way to determine how much of the content being streamed has been completely downloaded.

Comment: Is it possible to control the buffering sizes using 
QIODevice * QMediaPlayer::mediaStream() const

Answer (score 1):

The buffer size is based on the keyframes contained in the video track, the range between 2 keyframes defines the size of each buffered piece and as far as I know this value cannot be modifed in any way from the client-side, the source video should be re-encoded with different parameters in order to modify the size of the buffering pieces. By any chance, are you using x264? if so, you should read about `keyint` and `min-keyint` from [MeWiki](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings#keyint), lower keyint = shorter buffered pieces.